# Изменение атрибутов SMART при дефрагментации

Tags: железо, диск, smart

Во время дефрагментации наблюдаю постоянное изменение атрибутов SMART

```
  1   Raw Read Error Rate
  7   Seek Error Rate
240   Head Flying Hours     (Always passing)
241   Total LBA Written     (Always passing)
242   Total LBA Read        (Always passing)
```

Скринвидео в реальном времени из Hard Disk Sentinel 5.50:

[image: скринвидео]

Какие из этого можно сделать выводы?

PS: Да, диск не новый и не в лучшем состоянии.

Comment: Ну, по крайней мере, изменение 241 и 242 атрибутов говорит о том, что дефрагментация действительно идёт: данные читаются, и записываются на новое место. А в 240, видимо, производитель в старших байтах хранит какую-то специфическую для себя информацию.

Comment: @Yaant, больше интересуют 1 и 7.

Comment: Тут, как я понимаю, тоже многое зависит от производителя. В интернетах пишут, что для Seagate, например, большие значения Raw Read Error Rate - совершенно нормальное явление...

Comment: @Yaant, да, Segate и есть.

Comment: Забей. Надо смотреть на `Power on Hours` и `Start/stop`, чтобы оценить возраст. А здоровье определяется только по `Rellocated Event` и `Rellocated Sector`. Ну `Temperature` можно смотреть. Остальное - вилами по воде писано и сильно зависит от марки и модели. Хочешь актуальной инфы - прогоняй через `mhdd\victoria` и держи sata-кабеле `26 AWG`.